# Redirecting subfolder call to another url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an url `https://www.example.com/myfolder/`

Here is my domain `https://www.example.com` and `myfolder` is a folder.

I want to redirect all calls which comes to `myfolder` folder to the address `http://www.test-example.com/myfolder/`

Example: initial address: `https://www.example.com/myfolder/country_code/abc,pqr` should be redirected to `http://www.test-example.com/myfolder/country_code/abc,pqr`

I tried to use the following .htaccess settings:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myfolder$

RewriteRule ^myfolder$ http://www.test-example.com/myfolder/ [QSA]
```

But I am getting an internal server error. How can I solve this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myfolder/(.*)$ http://www.test-example.com/myfolder/$1 [QSA]
```